# Минимальный шаг/значение text-shadow?

Tags: css

Минимальный шаг/значение для text-shadow? 0.1, 0.01, 0.001 ... ?

```
text-shadow: 0 0 .01px #ddd;
```

Есть ли разница восприятия этого параметра разными браузерами?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15300264/2050440 - общий ответ про не целые значения в css.

Comment: На данный момент вижу, что последние версии основных браузеров воспринимают 0.01 значение, чуть по-разному его отображая. А вот насчет меньших значений пока что ничего не нашел.